# How can I read .pem and .p12 certificates installed in the android device from my app without user interaction

Tags: android, x509certificate, pkcs#12, wifi

I need to add wifi which has Security **802.1x EAP** and an EAP method **TLS**. For this, I need to add the CA certificate and User certificate(which is p12). Both certificates are already installed in the device.

I have seen similar questions in StackOverflow, but It's didn't meet my requirement. I have only the name of certificates with me, with that name I need to read the certificate which is already installed in the device also please give me a solution to read the localKeyID in PKCS12 certificate.

I'm adding wifi network using [WifiEnterpriseConfig](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiEnterpriseConfig.html)